# Invalid Endpoint Error using heroku and MinIO

Tags: python, django, heroku, minio, python-django-storages

I am have a django site and I published it with heroku.
The files are stored in a local docker container with MinIO.
I am using django-storages for connecting to the MinIO Storage as it supports AWS S3,
with the AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = "(Computer IP):9000/".
In my local computer it works fine with (Computer IP):9000/.
And when I use localhost on my computer it works with no problem.
But in heroku says invalid endpoint.
I have port forwarded the 9000 and 9001 Ports and allowed them through the firewall.
What did I get wrong?

***Error Log***

ValueError at /admin/users/profile/add/

```
Invalid endpoint: (Computer IP):9000/

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    (Heroku IP)
Django Version:     3.2.5
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

Invalid endpoint: (Computer IP):9000/

Exception Location:     /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py, line 287, in create_endpoint
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version:     3.9.6
Python Path:    

['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python39.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

Server time:    Mon, 30 Aug 2021 09:37:06 +0000
```

***Settings.py - AWS Info***

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = "(ComputerIP):9000/"

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Thank you!

Comment: AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = "(ComputerIP):9000/". Will not evaluate to the ip because it is a string.  Also is your computer reachable from heroku?